# I have an OpenWRT VM connected to the WAN, how do I connect client VMs to the OpenWRT LAN using it as a gateway?

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

[image: Diagram of my MacPro with the OpenWRT and client VMs using the br0 bridge on the host]

I'm trying to setup a lab in KVM on my Ubuntu Linux machine.  My goal is to create a test lab in which I can test the configuration of my physical router for my home network, before moving it into production.  Of course the configuration on the physical network will differ a bit, but much of it can be tested in the lab environment first.

I watched a series of [videos on creating a bridge in Debian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgLQl-FhSws) for your KVM VMs.  From these I was able to obtain an internet connection for my OpenWRT Barrier Breaker VM via it's WAN card.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.85
   network 192.168.1.0
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast 192.168.0.255
   gateway 192.168.1.1
   bridge_ports eth1
   bridge_stp off
   bridge_fd 0
   bridge_maxwait 0
   dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1

iface br0 inet6 static
address fe80:21f:5bff:fe3b:73b1
netmask64
    pre-up echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/br0/autoconf
    post-down echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/br0/autoconf
```

**/etc/network** - Host Interface Configuration

From this I ended up with the following configuration in Virtual Machine Manager:

[image: Host Interface configuration in Virtual Machine Manager]
**Host Interface configuration in Virtual Machine Manager**

I also configured the OpenWRT VM wan interface with the following configuration:

```
config `switch` `eth0`
  option `enable` `1`

config `switch_vlan` `eth1`
   option `vlan` `0`
   option `device` `eth1`
   option `ports` `4 5` #wan

config `switch_vlan` `eth0_1`
   option `vlan` `1`
   option `device` `eth0`
   option `ports` `0` #lan 1

config `interface` `lan`
   option `ifname` `eth0.1`
   option `proto` `static`
   option `ipaddr` `192.168.100.1`
   option `netmask` `255.255.255.0`
   option `defaultroute` `0`
   option `peerdns` `0`
   option `nat` `1`

config `interface` `loopback`
   option ifname `log`
   option proto `static`
   option ipaddr `127.0.0.1`
   option netmask `255.0.0.0`

config interface `wan`
   option ifname `eth1`
   option type `bridge`
   option proto `static`
   option ipaddr `192.168.1.85`
   option gateway `192.168.1.1`
   option netmask `255.255.255.0`
   option dns `192.168.1.1`
```

**/etc/config/network** - OpenWRT VM network configuration

Thanks to this, I am now able to use `opkg` to download any packages I might need for the OpenWRT VM.

---

However, I'm only half way there; I'd like to place some client VMs on series of private networks behind the OpenWRT VM.  I did my best to setup the LAN ports, but I don't know how to connect the virtual interfaces of the OpenWRT VM and the client machines.

---

I also setup a virtual network using Virtual Machine Manager:

[image: The isolated virtual network configuration in Virtual Machine Manager]
**The Isolated Virtual Network, intnet,  configuration in Virtual Machine Manager**

I thought that on the OpenWRT VM if I connected an interface other than the WAN interface on to the inet network:

[image: The OpenWRT VM LAN interface connected to the inet virtual network]
**OpenWRT VM LAN interface configured to connect to the inet virtual network**

....and that if I also connected the client's single network interface to the inet network, (and of course configured them both inside the VM) that would be able to simulate the conditions of my physical network.

[image: Client machine interface configured to connect to the inet virtual network]
**Client machine interface configured to connect to the inet virtual network**

I'm not really certain on how to proceed, the libvirt documentation confuses me because I don't quite understand the virtual switch;  It seems to me that if the virtual switch on the isolated inet network has both the gateway and the client machine plugged into it, it should at the very least allow the OpenWRT VM and the client machine to ping each other, but this is not the case.

I'd like to verify that I have the libvert plumbing correct first, and the move on to fine tuning the configuration of the lan interfaces on the inet isolated virtual network on both vms.

Comment: You should be able to connect to your VM from your LAN, as it has private addresses.  But you need reverse NAT in your LAN-router and in your host machine, as it should work like a router for your VMs.

Comment: IPv4 and NAT are an uggly hack because of address depletion, not security.  If you would have IPv6, this would have been trivial, as IPv6 doesn't have NAT.

Comment: I live in America; we do not have our choice of ISPs and most of them do not have ipv6.  What the check is reverse nat and why do I need it on my physical router for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need two host bridges.

- br0 connects to the internet, and
- br1 is a dummy bridge where all of the openwrt clients connect.

The complete instructions for a dhcp wan interface are here: http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/qemu/qemu

I've not yet figured out how to use one static address where the host connects to the br1 bridge and gives openwrt full control of br0...that's another question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Can you draw me a diagram of what you are describing?  I always think of a bridge as taking two physical ports and putting them on the same network;  When we start talking about virtual switches this all gets kind of murky.

Comment: Take your diagram of the internal network. Drop the switch, and add multiple kvm's connected to Openwrt. (Not so good with pictures) Each KVM has one network attached to BR1 (a dummy network). They will all be served by Openwrt  with its LAN side connection running BR1.

Answer (score 0):

Just made the same setup myself and have been trying to solve the problem for four days. Finally I found a solution that worked. I have also posted the same here on

Turned out I overthinked the whole solution. Only one interface is needed. I assigned the physical interface of the host to the VM's as well. So instead of creating one bridge for the internal network of the VM's i just used the same interface for everything. All Virtual and physical machines now share the same LAN connected to the OpenWRT assigning IP's and serving as a DNS-forwarder.